# App is not launching when tapped on notification in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to s4 model so where run but in lollipop version,it isn't working.

My code:

```
              Intent myIntent = new Intent(CheckinService1.this,
                            Main1.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("check", "check");

                    sp.putCheckin(CheckinService1.this, "check");

                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                            .getActivity(CheckinService1.this, 0, myIntent,
                                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                    myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                    myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

                    myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context,
                            notificationTitle, notificationText,
                            pendingIntent);
                    notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                            myNotification);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Corrected Code**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CheckinService1.this,
                        Main1.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("check", "check");
                myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

                sp.putCheckin(CheckinService1.this, "check");

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                        .getActivity(CheckinService1.this, 0, myIntent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

                myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context,
                        notificationTitle, notificationText,
                        pendingIntent);
                notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                        myNotification);
```

here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29

Answer (score 1):

Try adding :

```
myNotification.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```